# docker for Mac. docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, webserver

I am learnin "Docker for Mac"

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (a34c7702ea21c78966efa14e3b573ca150d8a7f01feebd99c02ce5fe1aaa42bb): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says, that there is already a service listening to port 80 on your machine. You have to use a different port:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name webserver nginx
```

`-p 8080:80` binds port 8080 of your Mac with the port 80 of the container. This creates the link you need to access it at http://localhost:8080/

Comment: thanks a lot. @n20